# spring 3.2.0 classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework-web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I got these .jar's in my WEB-INF/lib directory

```
spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

What else do i need?

Answer (score 3):

It should be `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` without the dash in the package name. Just a typo in your `web.xml` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Factors which may cause the exception :

1. Jars are not added to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory
2. DispatcherServlet reference is not configured properly in `web.xml`

Can you upload the web.xml, project structure and verify the information above?